# perf - immigration of /proc/kallsyms and System.Map for remote analysis

Tags: linux-kernel, symbols, perf

How do you guys use

> perf

to perform offline analysis on user-space program from online servers?

I ran perf record to gather data and perf-archive to pack up and transfer to localhost to do perf report. But there is a load of missing symbols from libc and the kernel. How could I solve this?